# Recommendations for a Boost::ASIO based CORBA library

Tags: c++, boost-asio, corba

I'm looking for a CORBA kit. I need the IDL compiler plus libraries (or source) for the ORB. I don't really know a helluva lot more about CORBA, but we need to interface with a server whose functions are exposed via CORBA.

The requirements I've been given, in rough order of priority are:

1 - Low cost or license amenable to commercial (closed source) use.
2 - Performance performance performance - is there a Boost::ASIO based ORB?
3 - Simple to integrate for at least Windows and Linux development.

We measure our software's performance in microseconds, so I need to be sure that the underlying network latency has been kept to an absolute minimum, but also, personally, I don't want to wrestle with a half-finished or half-working project and I don't want integrating this stuff to become the whole project. Essentially I need to get this API built and be calling remote functions with as little fuss as possible. That might just be wishful thinking, but it's worth mentioning.

So, has anyone out there had RECENT experience integrating CORBA into modern desktop application project? What would you recommend to use, and what should I beware of?

Comment: I'd generally beware of making life choices that require you to know what CORBA stands for...much less be required to use it in 2011.  :-P

Comment: We're connecting to a stock exchange and this is how they roll. It certainly wouldn't be MY first choice for a protocol in 2011, but these things have a habit of staying in place far longer when there is huge amounts of money riding on things just working the way they have been. :-(

Comment: @HostileFork - CORBA may not be sexy, but I'd really be interested in what you think would be a *halfway* portable framework that fulfills the OPs requirement of *Performance performance performance*. (Obviously, as Derf posted - it's not as if he had a choice here.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently using **omniorb** for an embedded software in the telecommunication field.
As for your questions:

1. It is free even for commercial use. It comes with a LGPL license
2. I haven't mesured performances, but I've got good results in an embedded real-time project. (About your question on boost::asio: I'm pretty sure that an ORB based on boost::asio doesn't exist)
3. It's been tested on many platforms, including linux and windows.

Maybe you could give a try to omniorb. Otherwise you could try **TAO**: it's a real-time ORB, but I never used it.

Comment: +1 for omniORB. I currently use it successfully for communications btw. Windows Desktop Apps. I should add, that *as far as I have been able to tell*, `omniORB` should be less hassle to get up and running but `TAO` seems to have more bells&whistles.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no ORB that is bui;d on top of boost::asio. I would recommend you to have a look at [TAO](http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu) or [TAOX11](http://www.taox11.org) which is a modern CORBA implementation. There is a free [CORBA Programmers Guide](https://www.remedy.nl/opensource/corbapg.html) with some starter information by Remedy IT, or the OCI Developers Guide.